# How to find exact Class of a table in any website while doing web scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Tourism/Travel-and-Tourism-Total-Contribution-to-GDP/Contribution-of-travel-and-tourism-to-GDP"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
elem=soup.find_all("table",class_="rank")
len(elem)
```

This is giving me length 0. Actually i want to import table from given website into pandas data frame but unable to findout exact Class of a table in given website link [Link](https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Tourism/Travel-and-Tourism-Total-Contribution-to-GDP/Contribution-of-travel-and-tourism-to-GDP). Can Anyone use above code and fix it?

Comment: It looks like the table is generated using javascript. The requests does not get all the js generated values. i suggest you to use selenium based solutions for this site.

Answer (score 0):

The website has a bunch of json outputs with the data. Just make a get request to `https://knoema.com/api/1.0/data/WTTC2019?time=2000,2005,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018&country=1001700,1001680,1001870,1001740,1001110,1001920,1001130,1001120,1001750,1001770,1001580,1001650,1001610,1001720,1001950,1001910,1001760,1001730,1001670,1001640,1001690,1001630,1001710,1001620,1001800,1001660,1001590,1001930,1001980,1001150,1001790,1001820,1001840,1001940,1001890,1001960,1001970,1001780,1001810,1001900,1001160,1001600,1001850,1001140,1001880,1001830,1000360,1001240,1001260,1001430,1000290,1001390,1001440,1000260,1001400,1000340,1000370,1000490,1000300,1001410,1001270,1001420,1001220,1000020,1000050,1000100,1000130,1000190,1000200,1000210,1000090,1000860,1000110,1000160,1000830,1000900,1000880,1000890,1000780,1000850,1000220,1000040,1000150,1000180,1000450,1000590,1000660,1000670,1000310,1000600,1000640,1000740,1000680,1000690,1000520,1000530,1000620,1000750,1000550,1000560,1000700,1000710,1000510,1000610,1000720,1000570,1000630,1000380,1000650,1000420,1000430,1000330,1000470,1000400,1000390,1000280,1000410,1000320,1000440,1000350,1000580,1000480,1000730,1001180,1001190,1001200,1001290,1001320,1001360,1001370,1001300,1001330,1001520,1001350,1001310,1001230,1001250,1001280,1001530,1001500,1001550,1001540,1001560,1001490,1001510,1001460,1001470,1001480,1000950,1000800,1000770,1000810,1000820,1000920,1000840,1000910,1000940,1000790,1000870,1000930,1000540,1000460,1000970,1001090,1001020,1001040,1001050,1000990,1000980,1001080,1001000,1001070,1001010,1001030,1001060&variable=1000100&measure=1000020&frequencies=A`.

That website also has a python package that you can check out for their api: `https://pypi.org/project/knoema/`